# Creating custom component library with object prefix in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a separate object/class that contains all the React components instead of adding a prefix to each component. For example, I can have a button for that has my custom styling and functionality.

For example BootStrap has  class but I would like to create another Button component that is prefixed with a object instead of making ProjectButton.

I'm not good with javascript, so I need some guidance on how to do this.

```
class ProjectForm extends React.Component {
 <Project.Button />         //javacript complains
 <Button />                //works
}

class Project.Button extends React.Component {
// ...
}

class Button extends React.Component {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is just that.. and object, not a class. Your object can have keys that represent your inner classes:

```
var Project = {
  Button: class Button extends React.Component {}
}

..
render() { return <Project.Button /> }
..
```

You'll see this out in the wild sometimes because you will be importing several components then namespacing them during your import:

```
// components.js
export class Button1 extends React.Component { }
export class Button2 extends React.Component { }

// somewhere-else.js
import * as Project from './components'

..
render() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Project.Button1 /> 
      <Project.Button2 /> 
    </div>
  )
}
..
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have asked how to add namespace to React Components.